# D3.js mouseover not active when markers too close together

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js

I have developed a google map which uses image markers. I want to display an information box when the cursor is over the marker but when markers are close together (not necessarily overlapping) the information box does not display.

What controls the minimum distance between markers required for mouseover to be activated?

Comment: Could you show us the code please?

Comment: Clickable region of a marker image is defined by google.maps.MarkerShape object which could be retrieved using marker.getShape(). I don't know if the same region is used for mouseover/out events. Most probably it is. But, as Lars said, better to show some code. Maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Here is a fiddle from a chat I had with FernOfTheAndes on another issue: jsfiddle.net/5XGAa/10. It is very similar to the one having the problem.

Comment: And here is the page http://tcan.ca/google-map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your markers is an `<image>` inside its own `<svg>`.  The images may only be 16px*16px, but the SVGs are 160px*20px, and that entire area is grabbing mouse events.  When your markers are close together, that means that an invisible portion of the SVG for one marker is blocking the mouse event from passing through to the visible marker below.

Changing the CSS to ignore mouse events on the `<svg>`, and only respond on the visible parts of the `<image>` seems to get things working as expected:

```
.members svg {
   pointer-events: none;
}
.members svg image {
  pointer-events: visiblePainted;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One more thing to learn. I adjusted the css for the members svg to 16x16 instead although I will consider your suggestion in case modifying the svg does not work properly (it appears to do so now.)

Comment: That's certainly another way to do it!  I wasn't sure if there were any graphics or text that needed that extra space, so I didn't suggest it.  You might still notice an invisible overlap on the corners, but it should be a lot more intuitive.